# Replacing a stuck stopcock - what could possibly go wrong?

Tags: plumbing

The main water feed is a lead pipe. The stopcock has apparently been replaced at some point but is now stuck. I managed to turn it off once before but it required more force that I think is wise. So I'd like to replace it before I start some other plumbing maintenance that will require me to actually close the stopcock. Also it's not exactly useful for emergencies as it currently is.  It looks like I should just be able to unscrew it and fit a replacement. But is there anything else I should be aware of?

[image: stopcock]

Comment: Unless main water is turned off, expect a flood.  Try wrapping a rag around it soaked with vinegar for a few hours first and see if it turns easier.  Lead pipe should be replaced with something safer.

Comment: There may be a "street valve" outside somewhere to shut your water service off.  Often this is near the water meter.  You might look around for that and see if you can turn it off there which will allow you to disassemble this and replace or repair your inside shutoff.  I second the recommendation to REPLACE this lead pipe with a non-toxic material.  Yes that will be a bit costly but so is lead poisoning.  If you have children in the home DO NOT let them drink the tap water!!

Comment: Wow, the only service I will do to lead is remove it. I haven’t seen any supply line lead pipe in close to 20 years. I would agree that replacement of the line would be of high importance. What could go wrong? Lead leaks.

Comment: Lead pipe is pretty clearly the municipal supply; if the municipal water chemistry is properly managed, it's not a dire issue, and it's very likely that replacing the house line would simply mean "not *seeing* the lead pipe that your new pipe connects to" rather than "magically no lead in the elderly municipal system." This is a reality of old municipal systems, and where the water chemistry is properly managed, lead does not leach.

Comment: It is not a stopcock , it is a valve , probably a gate, maybe a globe/disc. Consumer valves are made cheaply ; I have had 2 fail internally recently . Yours has likely failed internally.  One point , the risk with lead is it's low strength so do not apply much torque directly to the lead when loosening the threaded connections.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some way to shut off the water when replacing the valve - that may require calling your water supplier, depending on local rules (if there's an outside shutoff that *they* own, they may not want *you* operating it - varies.)

In the case that there is no outside shutoff, there are fancy units that will freeze a short section of pipe to plug it, but you'd probably need to call a plumber who owns one - not a practical DIY tool for realistic budgets.

The valve you have may only need service (cleaning and lubrication), but if you are going to the bother of getting the water shut off to service it, I would replace it with a 1/4 turn ball valve, as I have much less trouble with those for shutoff service (they tolerate sitting idle for years without becoming impossible to operate, since they have a very simple mechanism with few parts to corrode and get stuck.) If you have the sort of valve you show, operating it on a regular schedule (like once a month) is the best bet for it being able to operate when it's needed.